# Do I need a new data model version when changing minimum count of a relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a Core Data database with several object models. In one of the relationships I have a minimum required count of 1 for one of my To Many relationships. Can I remove that minimum without forcing a migration or do I need to create a new model version to make that small change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did some more research on this and it turns out that removing the minimum **does** force a migration, so you must create a new model version even for that small of a change.